word choice: [watch/control/restrain your language]
I have made up the sentences below.
(1a) Suppose that you are working at a public event and hear someone swear. You said, "Watch your language."
(1b) Suppose that you are working at a public event and hear someone swear. You said, "Control your language."
(1c) Suppose that you are working at a public event and hear someone swear. You said, "Restrain your language."
Which word choice is correct? Thank you.

Edit
Let's look at which are the most appropriate rather than which are correct.
Only watch is in the list of the most common collocations with your language, VERB your language; control and restrain are not.
Please note there are
many false positives in "watch your language".  They include book titles and usages of the type 'watch your language skill grow'.
Although mind isn't there, I would use it, as in mind your language
Edit
Also possible is moderate your language, used by many educated British people in formal occasions.

In  a more formal situation, many educated British people might say 'moderate your language'.

Thanks, @Michael Harvey.
I've added your point to the answer.

Again, not 'which is correct' but 'which is most appropriate'.

Thanks, @Kate Bunting.   I've added the first paragraph.
